# Access a factory in the same module in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wonder why I can't access a factory within the same module.

As I think it is better to build a web app with different independent modules, I would like to group all methods (services, factories, directives, ...) within the same module.

What do I do wrong?

```
app = angular.module("MyGreatModuleProvider", []);

app.factory("MyFactory", function($rootScope, $scope) {
  return {
    myFunction: function() {
      console.log("Hello World");
    }
  }
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, MyFactory) {
  MyFactory.myFunction();
  // This doesnt't work, unknown provider
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factories don't have a `$scope`

If you remove the `$scope` and only keep the `$rootScope` it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can remove both `$scope` and `$rootScope` from the factory declaration. [Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KEEzgr6XU72GOU8mWTLJ?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Define your injected object names to let the Angular know what to inject into fields:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', 'MyFactory', function($scope, MyFactory) {
  MyFactory.myFunction();
}]);
```

It's a good practice especially if you are going to compile your application.

Moreover as others pointed out: factories doesn't have $rootScope and $scope.